# Getting a list of attached documents and downloading them into local storage using Microsoft Graph API in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am developing a UWP app using `Microsoft Graph` API. I am getting a list of meetings for the current day for a `logged in` user using the below `API`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView?startDateTime=2017-06-20T20:00:00.0000000&endDateTime=2017-06-21T10:00:00.0000000
```

While creating the meeting , I had attached a `document` in the invite for the invited participants.
The `JSON` Response received has `"hasAttachments": true,`. My requirement is to download the file that were send in the invite.
I need to download those files in using my app and then attach them and send it to the `participants`. How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried and how is the behavior different than what you expect? Showing the effort (and code) you made to solve your problem will help attract answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My requirement is to download the file that were send in the invite.

It seems like you are using [List calendarView](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendarview) API to get the events. In that case you should be able get the event "id" property of the [Event](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/event) resource you want from the response, please check `"id": "string (identifier)"`.

After then, you can get all the  attachments of this event by [List attachments](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/event_list_attachments) API, and get a special one attachment by [Get attachment](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/attachment_get). You could get the binary contents of the attached file by `contentBytes` property which  contains the base64-encoded contents of the file. If your attachment is [fileAttachment resource type](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/fileattachment). For example, if the attachment is a `.txt`  file, you can download it and save it in application [local folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalFolder) as follows:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string token =await AuthenticationHelper.GetTokenForUserAsync();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);
HttpResponseMessage httpresponse = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{id}/attachments/{id}"));
StorageFile downloadedfile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("attachment.txt",CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting); 
JObject resObj = JObject.Parse(await httpresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
string contentbyte = resObj["contentBytes"].ToString();
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(downloadedfile, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(contentbyte)));
```

Update:
If the attachment is not a `.txt`, what actually needed is correctly transfer the base64-encode contents to file, for example:

```
StorageFile downloadedfile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("attachment.xlsx", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);    
string contentbyte = "contentbyte";
byte[] filecontent = Convert.FromBase64String(contentbyte);
await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(downloadedfile, filecontent);
```

Comment: this code holds good for text documents , what about other documents like .docx, .xls, .pdf and .pptx and others?

Comment: @Apoorv, these file formats you mentioned should work. I tested `.docx` and `.xls` they worked well. See my update.

Comment: one more thing , I want to check the meetings that are there when the user logs in (System Time ) and till the end of the current day. I want the time to be converted to the timezone and display the time accordingly. How can I do it ?